# RegEx for decimal numbers in string

Tags: php, regex

```
SetColoursSizes('0', '[Select Colour]', '0', '[Select Size]', 0,585.00,500.00);
```

This is an example of the string I'd like to match in PHP, and then caputre the last two variables, in case, '585.00' and '500.00'. Note: these numbers should be flexible in that they could be anything from 0.50 to $1500.00.

Can anyone help with the PHP/RegEx for this?

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is your PHP regexing other PHP?

Comment: No, it was scraping a page so it was regexing Javascript nested within a whole HTML page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code captures your final two number/decimal arguments in $matches[2] and $matches[3]:

```
<?php
  $matches = array();
  preg_match('/SetColoursSizes\(([^,]+,\s*){5}(\d+\.?\d*),\s*(\d+\.?\d*)/', "SetColoursSizes('0', '[Select Colour]', '0', '[Select Size]', 0,0.50,500.00);", $matches);
  print_r($matches);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This regex will work:

```
SetColoursSizes\s*\([^(]+,\s*([0-9.$]+)\s*,\s*([0-9.$]+)\s*\)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('~([\d\.]+),\s*([\d\.]+)\);$~', $yourString, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]` should have the two numbers.